# MySql Php Update is not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing some issue with update in Mysql Php..

Here is the code I am using

```
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name  = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $char ='this is chara'; //$_REQUEST['character'];
    $des  = $_REQUEST['des'];
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

$sql_update = "UPDATE cast SET name ='".$name."',Gendor ='".$email."', character = \'ashokkumar2\',description ='".$des."' WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result=mysql_query( $sql_update);
if ($result){
    echo 1;
}
```

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: Ever heard of SQL Injections?

Comment: Also, you do not need to escape the single quotes on ashokkumar2.

Comment: No need to escape the single quotes. you just directly write this way. `Gendor ='".$email."', character = 'ashokkumar2',`
If dynamically `Gendor ='".$email."', character = '".$char"',`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use mysql_* functions instead use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) because your script is completely open to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
character = \'ashokkumar2\'
```

should be

```
`character` = 'ashokkumar2'
```

`character` is [a reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL so you need to escape the word with tildas. Another way to avoid issues with reserved words is to name your columns with multiple words separated by underscore such as `character_name`.

If you need more information print the output of [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) after you run the query.

Remember, do not use mysql_* instead use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: `character= \'ashokkumar2\'` should be `character`= 'ashokkumar2'. Note that character is a reserved word in MySQL and hence should be back ticked

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll add your info into my answer, thanks!

Comment: Yes for sure, that is why I put it here to complement your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql_update = "UPDATE cast SET name=$name,Gendor=$email,character='$char',description=$des WHERE id = $id";
$result=mysql_query($sql_update);
if ($result){
    echo 1;
}
```

Comment: No down vote but this is so very wrong. Those string values need to be enclosed in quotes for that query to work

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer doesn't work, can you copy and paste the output of:
print $sql_update

Maybe this give us the answer more clear.